# How to get the original data type of an argument before it's implicitly converted

Tags: php, type-declaration

PHP type declaration comes with coercive mode as default mode, so it's possible to change the declared type and no `TypeError` will be thrown only if it's possible for PHP to coerce values of the wrong type into the expected ones.

Now let's say we have a function that accepts only integers as it's argument, so when a user passes a float number it will be converted implicitly into an integer type. Is there any possible way to detect from within this function that a user entered float without omitting the declared data type?

```
function doSomething(int $number) {
    var_dump($number); //  want something like int(5), user entered float(5.5)
}

doSomething(5.5)
```

***Edit***

A possible solution comes to mind is this

```
function doSomething(int $number) {
    var_dump($GLOBALS['num']);
}

$num = 5.5;
doSomething($num)
```

But i don't like it

Comment: No answer, but thanks for bringing up something I had a misconception on.  I presume you’d have to set to strict and catch the error, adjust as necessary and try again.  But using globals should make you uneasy...

Comment: @TimMorton True, but then it'll be impossible to catch that error from within the function.

Comment: Agreed. Another thing that comes to mind is asking “why do you need to know?”— because if you need to treat it differently, then shouldn’t you either have a different function, or translate the value before injecting it? (working this out in my head, too)

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess the way I would lean is to not type hint the overloading method, since you are expecting multiple types.  I suspect that will affect type hinting down the road, but that's a road I haven't traveled.  Interesting dilemma...